# ERROR: Could not find specified Maven installation 'maven_5_6_2'

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkinsfile (see below) which runs a number of commands. I have the 'Pipeline Maven Integration' plugin installed in my Jenkins server (I have version 3_10_0 of Pipeline Maven Integration installed in Jenkins). But when I try to run my pipeline I get the error below in the console. Am I missing something? Is the error complaining about the Jenkins Maven plugin or the version of Maven in my Java solution?

Jenkinsfile:-

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage ('Compile Stage') {
            steps {
                withMaven(maven: 'maven_3_8_4') {
                    sh 'mvn clean install'
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage ('Test Stage') {
            steps {
                withMaven(maven: 'maven_3_8_4') {
                    sh 'mvn test'
                }
            }
        }
        stage ('Cucumber Reports') {
            steps {
                cucumber buildStatus: "UNSTABLE",
                fileIncludePattern: "**/cucumber-report.json",
                jsonReportDirectory: 'target'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error in console:-

> ERROR: Could not find specified Maven installation 'maven_3_10_0'.
> Finished: FAILURE

Further information I have version 3.8.4 of Maven installed on the machine running the Jenkins server. I have also updated the Jenkins global tools config to reference version 3.8.4 of Maven, bit I still get the same error when running the pipeline.

Comment: The configuration in the global tools configuration is wrong...

Comment: Hi khmarbaise. I am in Global tools in Jenkins now. When you say the configuration is wrong, what exactly do you mean? Thanks

Comment: either the name you have configuration in global tools configuration is not the same as you use in your script or the name is correct but the version you installed related to it does not exists ...depending on how you configured to get the needed version...

Comment: @ED209, wanted to vote to close this Q, but can't determine the rigjt flag. You obviously had a user error of some sort amd the Q refers to maven 5.6.2 and 3.10.0, neither of which exist (latest:3.8.4). Any answer doea not contribute to the S/O body of knowledge. Pls just delete the Q.

Answer (score 2):

I worked it out, the reference should have been as follows in the Jenkinsfile (as this is what is n my global tools):-
[image]